# Querying dynamic hierarchical data from elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index in elasticsearch containing document with a format similar to this:

```
{id:base}
{id:a parent:base}
{id:b parent:a}
{id:c parent:a}
{id:d parent:someotherbase}
```

Simply put - each document has an id and a parent, a document can have multiple 'children' and only one parent.
Id like retrieve these document (based on the top 'base' document id) and transform this into a tree structure such as :

```
{id:base, children :[
   {id:a , children:[{id:b},{id:c}]},
   {...}
 ]}
```

is there a way to build a query that will return only the documents releavent for a single 'tree' (leaving the actual tree structure building to be implemented by me?
is there a way to quickly build this kind of structure using native elasticsearch support?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to denormalize the data before storing into elasticsearch.

ie.

```
{ node:base }
{ node:base/a}
{ node:base/a/b }
```

And then use [path hierarchy tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html). That will help to query documents.